# C# dynamicly select attribute for sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I've got an arraylist with objects, now I need to sort them.

I've got this method:

```
public Int32 CompareTo(object next)
        {
            SessionInfo nextCase = (SessionInfo)next;
            return (this.Duration.CompareTo(nextCase.Duration));
        }
```

Now I need to dynamicly change the sortvalue from "Duration" to "Name"
So I made an attribute called SortColumn and gave it value "Duration"

Now my code looks like this:

```
public string SortColumn { get; set; }

public SessionInfo()
    {
        SortColumn = "Duration";
    }

public Int32 CompareTo(object next)
    {
        SessionInfo nextCase = (SessionInfo)next;
        return (this.SortColumn.CompareTo(nextCase.SortColumn));
    }
```

This is not working.
Is there a way to change the column to sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than an arraylist, why not use a generic list, then you get sorting for free (almost):

```
var list = new List<SesionInfo>(); // then add items
list.Sort((s1,s2) => s1.SortColumn.CompareTo(s2.SortColumn));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int CompareTo(object next)
{
    SessionInfo nextCase = (SessionInfo)next;
    if(SortColumn == "Duration")
        return (this.Duration.CompareTo(nextCase.Duration));
    else if(SortColumn == "Name")
        return (this.Name.CompareTo(nextCase.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is not working is that it is sorting by the value of the SortColumn property and all of the objects in your collection have the same value for this.  One way to solve it is to use reflection to get the value of the property named by the SortColumn property.

```
public Int32 CompareTo( object next )
{
      SessionInfo nextCase = next as SessionInfo;
      var sortProperty = this.GetType().GetProperty( this.SortColumn );

      var currentValue = sortProperty.GetValue( this ) as IComparable;
      var nextValue = sortProperty.GetValue( next ) as IComparable;

      return currentValue.CompareTo( nextValue );
}
```

I've left out the nullity checks to simplify the example, but you'll need to consider what happens if the properties aren't comparable, the values are null, etc.

A better solution would be to use a generic list and OrderBy extension.  Then you can simply do:

```
var sorted = collection.OrderBy( c => c.Duration );
```

or

```
var sorted = collection.OrderBy( c => c.Name );
```

If you use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), then you can specify the column by name.

```
var sorted = collection.OrderBy( "Duration" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would agree, always use generic list for this sort of functionalities as you get the following advantages,

- Type Safety
- Better performance
- No need for explicit casting
- Better growth algorithms.

Regards,

Sal Zaki